# css chrome issue at footer cross browsers (IE,FF,Chrome)

Tags: css, footer

my footer is missed up cross all browser cant figure out a away to fix and make it work fine with FF(4,5) IE(7,8,9) Chrome

any hint to fix footer

http://www.contactskeeperapp.com

Comment: the problem is : the footer black background is not fixed means each browser take a a new higher and soical bottons also not taking the same places in all browser if its fixed in IE and FF its mess in chrome and so on :)

Comment: Make sure your html is valid first: http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3a%2f%2fwww.contactskeeperapp.com%2f

Comment: thanks zippy am aware of it i need to take care of css then will validate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by setting a fixed `height` for your `div#footer`.

Comment: i did and this works 70% of the fix  now 2 things need to be fixed : the black bg in footer IE is size bigger than FF and Chrome , 2nd the Google + botton in Chrome no the same line as other social bottons

Comment: the fix is live u can see what i mean